# Share resources between layouts in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, actionmailer

OK, so Ive set up my mailer in Rails which works fine, but I wanted to make a new action (or maybe just a view?) to have a slimmed down contact form in a lightbox. I can do that all fine and dandy but it would use the default layout which I dont want. So I added:

```
render :layout => 'lightbox'
```

to the action so that I could use a new layout. Unfortunately that seems to block off my access to the model as I get this error when the lightbox pops up

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
 #on this line
<% form_for @contact, :url => {:action => "create"}, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
```

So by using a different layout I cant use the resources I set up in my routes which is here:

```
  resources :contacts, :only => [:new, :create], :as => :contacts
  #Im passing in a name to the email form
  match "contacts/direct/:name" => "contacts#direct", :as => :direct_email
```

I hope that made sense. But what do I do?

Comment: 1. are you creating @contact before you call your render :layout => 'lightbox'?
2. is your lightbox call via ajax? if possible please post all your controller code